# insert strings/words to variable from file and join separator instead of space/s

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, perl

We have the following file ( it is example )

```
more machines.txt


Node23
Node34
Node12
Node95
Node23
```

We want to insert the list of all node to variable and join each node with “,” separator

Example of expected results ( without empty space/s )

```
Node23,Node34,Node12,Node95,Node23
```

We try this

```
LIST=` sed -e 's/\s\+/,/g'  machines.txt `
```

But we this approach not join the separator between machines , and we get

```
echo $LIST

Node23 Node34 Node12 Node95 Node23
```

what is the right approach to get the csv list in variable ( this syntax should be in bash script )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `paste`:

```
list=$(paste -sd, < machines.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` command evaluates line-by-line by default. As a result, your command is not replacing the newline. You can confirm this by running:

```
echo "$LIST"
```

which would show you that you actually did not do any operation on the original file contents.

Since you are only replacing one character, I would recommend the `tr` tool as an alternative to `sed`. The resulting command would look something like this:

```
LIST=$(tr '\n' ',' < machines.txt)
```

Basically the line means that we want to replace newlines `\n` with a comma `,`

If there's a trailing comma, you can also add in a `sed` command to remove the final comma.

```
LIST=$(tr '\n' ',' < machines.txt | sed 's/,$//')
```

Comment: one problem in your approach that we get also separator in the end , example - Node23,Node34,Node12,Node95,Node23, while we should get - Node23,Node34,Node12,Node95,Node23

Comment: That means you have a `\n` at the end of your file. You can remove it via a `sed` or some other tool. I'll modify my answer with a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
$ LIST=$(echo $(<machines.txt) | sed 's/ /,/g')
$ echo "$LIST"
$ Node23,Node34,Node12,Node95,Node23
```